# Changes I'm making in the code don't take place

Tags: c#, xna

I'm working on a game in XNA framework.
for some reasons changes I make in the code doesn't change the game.
It became so ridiculous I actually tried this code:

```
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (false)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();
            ProcessNetworkMessages();
            if (!IsHost)
            {
                KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();
                localPlayer.Update(gameTime, oldState, newState, board);
            }
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
    }
```

and the game still runs as usual.

Comment: ... And the question is? Also, please note that without any details we can't help you.

Comment: the question is why? why the changes I make don't affect the game? what more details do you need? I just made the update method unreachable (if(false)) and the game still runs normally. Why and how can I solve it?

Comment: Probably because your code is not compiling and executing properly or your logic is wrong.

Comment: What can cause the code not to compile and execute properly? and my logic might be wrong but how? the XNA methods are well known and even if I make one unreachable it still works, It can't be!

Comment: it might be because I have some errors? but it's still runnable

Comment: "If you change something, but it doesn't appear to change, then you didn't change it." Lesson I learned in 1975.

Comment: If you have compile time errors, then the project is not really building, so most likely what is running is the last good compiled copy of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised nobody here has a clue to a obvious mistake...

A if statement runs if the answer is true, and it will skip if the answer is false. So if you put false it is obvious it does not run your code. If you change it to true it will always run your code no matter what. Putting true or false directly into an if statement is like commenting out lines of code or not.

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (false) //<--- The answer is false, let's not run this code block!
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();
            ProcessNetworkMessages();
            if (!IsHost)
            {
                KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();
                localPlayer.Update(gameTime, oldState, newState, board);
            }
            base.Update(gameTime);
        } // Start running code from here -->
    }
```

Basically you are not updating anything, this code is just not running. Try a line break inside the if statement to see it does not run.